# Change GUI in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, thread-safety, sendmessage

I have an operation which ends in about 20 seconds. To avoid freezing, I want to create a thread and update a label text in it every second. I searched a lot, since everyone has different opinion, I couldn't decide which method to use.

I tried SendMessage and it works but some people believe that using SendMessage is not safe and I should use PostMessage instead. But PostMessage fails with `ERROR_MESSAGE_SYNC_ONLY` (1159).

```
char text[20] = "test text";
SendMessage(label_hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, text);
```

I searched about this and I think it's because of using pointers in PostMessage which is not allowed. That's why it fails.

So, what should I do? I'm confused. What do you suggest? Is this method is good for change UI elements in other thread?

Thanks

Comment: Did "some people" mention why it is not safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `ERROR_MESSAGE_SYNC_ONLY` says:

> The message can be used only with synchronous operations.

This means that you can use synchronous message delivery, i.e. `SendMessage` and similar, but you cannot use asynchronous message delivery, i.e. `PostMessage`.

The reason is that `WM_SETTEXT` is a message whose parameters include a reference. The parameters cannot be copied by value. If you could deliver `WM_SETTEXT` asynchronously then how would the system guarantee that the pointer that the recipient window received was still valid?

So the system simply rejects your attempt to send this message, and indeed any other message that has parameters that are references.

It is reasonable for you to use `SendMessage` here. That will certainly work.

However, you are forcing your worker thread to block on the UI. It may take the UI some time to update the caption's text. The alternative is to post a custom message to the UI thread that instructs the UI thread to update the UI. Then your worker thread thread can continue its tasks and let the UI thread update in parallel, without blocking the worker thread.

In order for that to work you need a way for the UI thread to get the progress information from the worker thread. If the progress is as simple as a percentage then all you need to do is have the worker thread write to, and the UI thread read from, a shared variable.

Comment: So, SendMessage will be ok for changing UI elements. You said that I force UI thread to process my message which causes a block, but I think it's not a big deal. Right? By the way, how can I pass text string using PostMessage (since you suggested to use custom message)?

Comment: Yes, `SendMessage` as written in your question will work. Although you should declare the string as `const char *text = "test text"` or `char text[] = "test text"` rather than the code in your question. That runs the risk of not being null terminated.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning, because `SendMessageCallback` returns the same error code, and there's clearly no problem passing a user buffer to that function, since you can properly deallocate it on return. So what gives?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error says it all. The message cannot be sent asynchronously. The thing about `PostMessage` is that it posts the message to the listening thread's queue and returns immediately, without waiting for the result of message processing. `SendMessage` on the other hand, waits until the window procedure finishes processing the message and only then it returns.

The risk of using `PostMessage` in your case is that before window procedure processes the message you may have deallocated the string buffer. So it is safer to use `SendMessage` in this instance and that's what MS developers probably thought about when they decided not to allow asynchronous posting of this particular message.

EDIT: Just to be clear, of course this doesn't eliminate the risk of passing a naked pointer totally.

Comment: So, do you suggest using SendMessage to update UI elements? It can be updating a textbox text or changing progressbar value.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644953.aspx)

**If you send a message in the range below WM_USER to the asynchronous message functions (PostMessage, SendNotifyMessage, and SendMessageCallback), its message parameters cannot include pointers. Otherwise, the operation will fail.**

Answer (score 3):

The asynch PostMessage() alternative requires that the lifetime of the data passed in the parameters is extended beyond the message originator function.  The 'classic' way of doing that is to heap-allocate the data, PostMessage a pointer to it, handle the data in the message-handler in the usual way and then delete it, (or handle it in some other way such that it does not leak).   In other words, 'fire and forget' - you must not touch the data in the originating thread after the PostMessage has been issued.

The upside is that PostMessage() allows the originating thread to run on 'immediately' and so do further work, (maybe posting more messages).  SendMessage() and such synchronous comms can get held up if the GUI is busy, imacting overall throughput.

The downside is that a thread may generate mesages faster than the GUI can process them.  This usually manifests to the by laggy GUI responses, especially when performing GUI-intenisve work like moving/resizing windows and updating TreeViews.  Eventually, the PostMessage call will fail when 10,000+ messages are queued up.  If this is found to be a problem, additional flow-control may have to be added, so further complicating the comms, ( I usually do that by using a fixed-size object pool to block/throttle the originating thread if all available objects are stuck 'in transit' in posted, but unhandled, messages.

Comment: Thank you for your comment sir. It was pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use SendMessage safely here. Then you don't need to worry about memory persistence for your string and other issues.
SendMessage is not safe when you send messages from another message handler or send message to blocked GUI thread, but if in your case you know it is safe - just use it

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with the `PostMessage`but a problem with the message  you are sending - `WM_SETTEXT`. First a common misconception is that if you SendMessage() to a control from a thread, it is different from calling GUI API, it is in fact *NOT*. When you call a GUI API (from anywhere) for example to set text, windows implement this in the form of SendMessage() call. So when you are sending the same message, it is essentially same as calling the API. Although directly GUI access like this works in many ways it is not recommended. For this reason, I would beg to disagree with the accepted answer by @David.

The correct way is (code on the fly)

```
char* text = new char[20] 
strcpy_s(text, "test text");
PostMessage(label_hwnd, IDM_MY_MSG_UPDATE_TEXT, NULL, text);
```

you will updated the text in your own message IDM_MY_MSG_UPDATE_TEXT handler function and delete the memory.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You said that "Although directly GUI access like this works in many ways it is not recommended". Can you tell me why it isn't recommended? Thanks

Comment: @MalikÇelik That's a big question but generally it depends what you are doing..if only one thread is accessing GUI and it is not conflicting with GUI or other threads than its okay. However when you do without thread synchronization, the risk of overlooking something is there.

Comment: Aha, so what you are saying is general thread issue. This issue is valid for even a global integer. Threads should access it with caution. Thank you zadane